# Is the order of names of deities important?

Tags: name

A diety has several names. Ashtottara shatanamavali, Sahasranama etc.,

Do the order of names in such collection has any importance?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

In Vishnu Sahasranama of Bhishma, the categorization and order of names denotes 5 'places/murtis/avatara' of Bhagavan - Vaikunta, Ksheerabdi, Vibhava, Archa, Antaryami.

[Source - Parasar Bhattar Vyakhyanam](https://pravachanam.com/albumfilesbrowselist/338/321)

Personal opinion : It matters when it is part of a namavali, or a garland of names, or when it is part of a mantra. But for other times, it does not matter, just as a mother doesn't care if a child calls it amma, or mummy, or ma.